# Implement a list of scrollable records using in SVG using D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I want to implement a list of scrollable records in SVG using D3.js. And I do not know how could I move all records down or up once the height of a specific record changes.

Here is what I mean. Let us suppose we have a list of records (each record is represented using a nested `svg` and positioned using percentage values for position and dimensions relative to the root `svg`):

[image: record list sample]

Now I update the data inside one of the records, so that its height increases or decreases. As a result I need to move all the records below the record down or up.

[image: scrolled up list]

How can I do that? I thought about keeping an array of all the records and when one of them changes its height go through the array and update the `y` position of each one of them. But it seems very inefficient solution. Are there another ways to tackle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with SVG, and not html you'll probably have to implement your own scroll solution. I've done this a couple of years ago by keeping a list of items in the container, if a new item is added, you first update what should be visible, and then update the positions of those visible items. If y/x coords get out of bounds, you remove them from the dom, here is what I mean:

[image: example]

[LINK TO ABOVE EXAMPLE](http://bl.ocks.org/ibrahimtanyalcin/3ec054bc6dc485c46631c5ef1d28dbe9)

Another solution could be to use SVG [foreignObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) and directly embed the HTML, that would be much easier I guess.

Comment: The `foreignObject` is not a solution in this case. If I create the following hierarchy: root `svg` > `foreignObject` > `div` which scrolls on overflow > `svg`, then the scroll does not work in Chrome. But I guess what you provided is the best I can expect. Thank you.

Comment: I assumed there would be browser vendor gotchas. Then implement your own solution, at each time you drag the handler -->slice the array of items to determine what should be visible --> enter/update/exit to update the DOM nodes. Btw, I would file a bug report for chrome if I were you, foreignObject is supposed behave identical as in an xhtml parent.